# Как правильно задать функцию для фитирования массива?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy

Имеется следующий код, читающий данные из текстового файла (файл можно скачать по [ссылке](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1a8HFXpuQlB4B5BFWtg2jleEFwVscpJqh/view?usp=sharing)):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit


def function_of_phase_transition(x, a, b):
    if x <= a:
         return (1 - x/a)**b
    else:
         return 0

# смотрим файл output

with open('output', 'r') as f:
    tring = f.read()
    list_of_str = string.split("\n")

list_with_temp = []
list_with_magnetization = []

numbers_of_useful_strings = np.arange(8, 49)
for number in numbers_of_useful_strings:
    list_with_temp.append(float(list_of_str[number].split('\t')[0]))
    list_with_magnetization.append(float(list_of_str[number].split('\t')[1]))

array_with_temp = np.array(list_with_temp)
array_with_magnetization = np.array(list_with_magnetization)


plt.plot(array_with_temp, array_with_magnetization, ".", label="Data")


popt, pcov = curve_fit(function_of_phase_transition, array_with_temp, 
array_with_magnetization)
plt.plot(array_with_temp, function_of_phase_transition(array_with_temp, *popt), label="fit")

plt.legend()

plt.show()
```

Надо сделать фит массива функцией следующего вида:

```
def func_of_transition(x, a, b):
    if x <= a:
        return (1 - x/a)**b
    else:
        return 0
```

Для этого я использую функцию `curve_fit` из `scipy.optimize`. В итоге, помимо ошибок внутри самих функций Python, я получаю ошибку в своем коде:

> ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Насколько я понял, вся проблема в условии `if x <= a` (если функцию заменить на линейную вида `a * x + b` без условного оператора, то все запускается и фитируется). Мне следует менять функцию `func_of_transition` (и если да, то как) или применять другую функцию библиотеки?

Answer (score 0):

Поскольку в этой функции у вас аргументы имеют тип `numpy.array`, то и использовать нужно подходящую функцию `Numpy`. Если я правильно понял задачу, то это будет `np.where`:

```py
def function_of_phase_transition(x, a, b):
    return np.where(x < a, (1 - x/a)**b, 0)
```